# Android: update of side-loaded apps

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update, sideloading

The getInstallerPackageName method is useful when assessing, for example, whether a PRO-KEY app (one that unlocks premium features in another app) was installed from the Google Play store or it was pirated.

That method is also useful for any app to assess whether it was installed from Google Play or it was side-loaded.

When apps are installed from Google Play, they are updated when Google Play has a newer version.

I would like to know whether even a sideloaded app is updated when Google Play has a newer version. I am asking for this because the above mentioned method yields another value for the sideloaded app.

Answer (score 1):

> sideloaded app is updated when Google Play has a newer version

Yes, it is.